# std::initializer_list and the = operator

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

If I do this:

```
 MyClass a=b;
```

This uses the copy constructor to initialize `a`, and the `=` operator overload is not involved, right?

The `=` operator would be used if `a` was already initialized and then I later assigned it to something else.

I saw [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
S(std::initializer_list<T> l) : v(l) {
```

Used like:

```
S<int> s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // direct list-initialization
```

This is interesting. It is initialization and it uses the `=` operator, but it is calling a constructor that is not a copy constructor. Why does it not instead take syntax like this:

```
S<int> s {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

That's how the `std::vector` [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) with an `std::initializer_list` works. It seems confusing to use an `=` operator to initialize an object when that operator is not calling copy construction, doesn't it?

Comment: [Test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=32e42256c131b9f31d69b59d16ccecbf-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> This uses the copy constructor to initialize a, and the = operator overload is not involved, right?

Exactly.

> Why does it not instead take syntax like this: [...]

You can use both forms, and they are mostly equivalent, except for the fact that the form using `=` is called *copy-list-initialization*, and it requires a non-`explicit` constructor (thanks to Nicol Bolas for the correction).

The form without the `=`, on the other hand, is called *direct-list-initialization* and it works (quite intuitively) by directly constructing your object from the initializer (passing the initializer as an argument to the constructor of the object to-be-initialized). Whether or not the constructor is `explicit` is not relevant here.

So in short, the two forms are equivalent except for the fact that *copy-list-initialization* won't work if your constructor is `explicit`. If that is not the case, which form to choose is mostly a matter of style.

Comment: [Explicit](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b09efd59be75e347c103c4bde4158689-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: I'd imagine that since it is passing the list to the constructor, you could also write it as a third option, as `S<int> s({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});`

Comment: indeed that is demonstrated here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4b01ae9fdd603fbab6f6667dec3b59ad-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba

Answer (score 4):

`MyClass a=b;` uses copy constructor only if `b` is of type `MyClass`.

If `b` was `OtherClass`, you would need another constructor, which is not the copy constructor, just another custom constructor taking `OtherClass` as argument (or more likely `const OtherClass&`, but that's irrelevant to the question - just preventing nitpickers :).

The same is with your example with `initializer_list`: It is a normal constructor for type `S`, which takes an initializer list as an argument. In that sense it doesn't differ from some hypothetical constructor `S(int n)`.

Imagine if you had:

```
S(int n) : v(n) {}  // ctor taking an int
```

You could create an instance like this:

```
S s = 4;
```

The same is for initializer list.